# Asp.net Webform loading twice when I click on the form link?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a simple asp.net webform project. When I click on the page, it run twice. I'm just calling two functions(Fill DropDowns) on `Page_Load` Event.

Debugging, first time the control comes in `Page_Load` function then, it call two other functions(Fill Dropdowns). But, when these two functions were called successfully, the control return again in the start position of the `Page_Load` function.

Any Help? Where is the problem?
I already checked this solution `AutoEventWireup="true"` to make it true and false. I attached the screen shots of the backend code front page please see here. [CodeView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vPby.jpg)
[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICodQ.jpg)
[JS File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pofNm.jpg)

Comment: Please, add your code in 'text'.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Is your code in Page_Load wrapped in a check for [IsPostBack](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/811684/Understanding-The-Complete-Story-of-Postback-in-AS)?

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
}
```